# Kendo DropDownList get element from json data other than dataTextField or dataValueField

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-dropdown

So i have two dropdownlists and i would like to get another json property from the second dropdownlist other than the ones attributed to dataTextField or dataValueField.
Here's the refered dropdownlist:

```
$("#campoFormLinha"+index).kendoDropDownList({

        optionLabel: "Campo",
        dataTextField: "name",
        dataValueField: "id",
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            serverFiltering:true,
            transport: {

                read:{
                    url:"${pageContext.request.contextPath}" + "/newlayout/mySearchesFormFieds.do",
                    data:function(){
                        return {formId: $("#dynamicFormLinha"+index).val()
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        cascadeFrom: "dynamicFormLinha"+index
    }).data("kendoDropDownList");
```

here's the json it returns:

> [{"id":9,"name":"Cliente","type":"STRING"},{"id":10,"name":"Contribuinte","type":"STRING"},{"id":11,"name":"Facturação","type":"STRING"},{"id":12,"name":"Conta","type":"STRING"},{"id":13,"name":"Factura","type":"STRING"},{"id":14,"name":"Valor","type":"STRING"}]

So assuming all this, i would like to get the type property according to the selected option.

How can i do this?

Comment: Can you provide description about what you have and you want?

Comment: Hi there! Currently everything is working well, i just want the property "type":"STRING" to be accessible. the "id" and "name" are already accessible via the dataTextField and dataValueField, but i would like to access the type property binded to the selected option. I assume this is possible, i tried using this selector:
$("#campoFormLinha1").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource._data, but this gives me all the options data.

Comment: You want "type":"STRING" of selected item, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getSlectedItem() {
        var ddl = $("#color").data("kendoDropDownList");
        alert(ddl.dataSource.data()[ddl.selectedIndex - 1].type);
    }

    function onSelect(e) {
        alert(e.sender.dataSource.data()[e.item.index() - 1].type);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var data = [
                { text: "Black", value: "1", type: "string" },
                { text: "Orange", value: "2", type: "int" },
                { text: "Grey", value: "3", type: "string" }
            ];

        $("#color").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "text",
            dataValueField: "value",
            dataSource: data,
            optionLabel: "select",
            select: onSelect
        });
    });

</script>
```

1. On selection you will get the type field of this item
2. On button click you will also get the type field of this item

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Oh i see you updated it. Can i ask you what does the parameter in onSelect is passing?

Comment: Still you have any concern?

Comment: See my previous question. :)